# Pagination in Magento2 widget block

Tags: magento2, blocks, widget, pagination

Hi is there any way to do pagination in widget block . For example  have a category with id 355 . I want to display that category product in a page . So I am using widget(following code)

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="0" products_count="160" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`355`^]^]"}}
```

But there are up to 155 product in that category the product are displaying in the page  . But for 155 product the page load time is too high . So If there will be pagination for that then its easy to load the products .

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can use this config for adding pagination in your widget]

You can use this config for adding pagination in your widget
and in result, you will get pagination in widget block